auth.js: OAuthAccountNotLinked: Another account already exists with the same e-mail address
In my Next.js application using auth.js (5.0.0-beta19), attempting to sign in with a different OAuth provider (e.g. Facebook) using an email address already associated with a sign-in of another provider (e.g. Google) results in a server-side error:
[auth][error] OAuthAccountNotLinked: Another account already exists with the same e-mail address. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#oauthaccountnotlinked
at handleLoginOrRegister (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/handle-login.js:255:23)
at async Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:65:50)
at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:39:24)
at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
at async /home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:55038
at async ek.execute (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:45808)
at async ek.handle (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:56292)
at async doRender (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1377:42)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1587:40)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1507:28)
at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1931:24)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1969:32)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:920:25)
at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:272:17)
at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:816:17)
at async /home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:339:20
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:336:24)
at async invokeRender (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:174:21)
at async handleRequest (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:353:24)
at async requestHandlerImpl (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:377:13)
at async Server.requestListener (/home/simon/devel/learn/next.js/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:141:13)

And the client side will be redirected to a page like this:

This looks like a built-in page provided by auth.js.
https://errors.authjs.dev#oauthaccountnotlinked mentioned the allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking option, but I don't want to turn it on for the providers, at the same time, I don't want this page to be shown to users. How to silently redirect the user to the website's signin page when this happens? Or is there a better way to handle this error?

presumably, you're using the database strategy? which one or which adapter?

@akdombrowski yes I'm using the database strategy, with Prisma and PostgreSQL, thanks

By default, the adapter creates an Account with a provider field tied to a user upon registering (see Concepts>Database Models in authjs docs or look in your database with a test user). The mismatch between that provider and the one that's currently being used to sign in is the cause of the error. Account linking lets this happen but is dangerous because not all providers verify email ownership. The alternative to allowing cross account linking is to customize the Prisma adapter. There are a number of different workarounds that'll depend on what you need and are willing to do.

I know that's the reason of the error, and I don't want to enable account linking. Is there any other way to prevent auth.js from showing this page to users?

Create a custom sign in page that handles it https://authjs.dev/guides/pages/signin. Or handle it with the signin callback https://authjs.dev/reference/core#signin
